# The navigator does not take the url that I indicate to him using Selenium on Python

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python

everyone. First, excuse me for my bad English. I will try to go a specific URL but just the browser its open.

This is my code
1 file:

```
from selenium import webdriver


class Objects:
    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()

    def open_page(self, url):
        return self.driver.get(url)
```

And in my second file I have:

```
from Objects.pom import Objects


driver = Objects()
base_url = {
    'eci_es' : 'url1',
    'eci_pt' : 'url2',
    'nw_back_rc' : 'url3',
    'wm_back_rc' : 'url4'
}


def login():
    driver.open_page(base_url.get('nw_back_rc'))
```

But just the browser it's open.

I will try to use POM

Answer (score 0):

When you call `driver = Objects()`, it will instantiate the browser (`self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()`).

But on the second script you just **define** a function that will call `driver.open_page`. You will need to **call** the function itself.